# Three equal columns in Bootstrap with centered text not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three columns in Bootstrap with both horizontally and vertically aligned text. The problem is that the columns are not equal in width, the third column is wider than each of the other two. The columns have different width contents, but each would fit into one third of the total width.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <footer class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom footer-bar">
        <div class="row display-tbl">
            <div class="col-xs-4 display-cell"><b>Opt1</b></div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 display-cell"><img src="img.jpg" height="40" width="64"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 display-cell"><b>Option 2</b></div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.footer-bar {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #606060;
}
.display-tbl {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed; /* <- makes no difference */
    width: 100%;
}
.display-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: all columns are of same width except the second column looks smaller because your image is having fixed width and height. try adding border:1px solid red; to your .display-cell class and see all three columns are of equal size

Comment: It has nothing to do with the image!

Comment: okay i copied your code and created a fiddle and all the columns look the same width. https://jsfiddle.net/ng2tgo3o/ just added "border:1px solid red;" style

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that you've added fixed width to your image, try this:

```
.display-cell img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

or use bootstrap responsive class for images:

```
.img-responsive
```

"Makes an image responsive (will scale nicely to the parent element)"

Check working example:

http://www.bootply.com/wDTiwG9V49

Comment: even if we don't add the above css still the divs are of equal size. it is only visually second column looks smaller.

Comment: No, changing the cell widths ruins the Bootstrap grid layout.  I placed text instead of an image in the second column and the columns were still not equal.

Comment: Yes if you try to add fixed width to the image, it will mess up the responsiveness, placing text in the columns will be no problem
http://www.bootply.com/KvBcWciYKT

Comment: I can either vertically centre the text and have unequal columns, or top align the text and have equal columns.  But what I want is vertically centred text with three equal columns.  The image is making the grid higher than the text.

Comment: can you create a fiddle with an example of what you are referring to, because I am kind of confused. Or edit the question with the exact text and image

Comment: you want fixed columns heights?

Comment: No I want fixed column widths, each column should be one third of the screen width.  The height will be 40, because that is the height of the image.  If I use the code as is in Firefox then the image is left of centre, indeed all the columns are left of where I would expect them to be.